# keep getting dai.balanceOf() is not a function

Tags: javascript, bots, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

So i am trying to make a bot that will automatically swap from dai to usdc continously until the balance of dai in my wallet decreases by 10%. So now i am trying to test this on Goeril test-net where i have deployed the Multiswap Smart contract that will do the swap to Uniswap usdc and Dai pool.

But im having the issue on the actual bot itself, everytime im trying to test the script it says that dai.balanceOf() is not a function. I have tried to fix this but i am completely stuck, and i also believe there are other issues with the script too.

Could someone please help.

Script for the Bot:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
var fs = require('fs');
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

const DAI = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F';
const ABI_FILE_PATH = 'artifacts/contracts/SwapExamples.sol/SwapExamples.json';
const DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0xAb54Bf58D1cf4F6E5fe14917fa909AaAc4c4cE91';
const dai = ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);

function waitforme(milisec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => { resolve('') }, milisec);
  })
}

async function getABI() {
  const data = await fsPromises.readFile(ABI_FILE_PATH, 'utf8');
  const abi = JSON.parse(data)['abi'];
  return abi
}

async function main() {

const {PRIVATE_KEY} = process.env;
const {INFURA_GORELI_ENDPOINT_KEY} = process.env;

let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(`https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/${INFURA_GORELI_ENDPOINT_KEY}`)

let signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const abi = await getABI();
const UniContract = new ethers.Contract(DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);
const balance = await dai.balanceOf(signer);

  for (let i = 0; i < 111; i++) {

  const amountIn = balance

  if (amountIn.mul(10).lte(balance.mul(9))) {break;}

  await dai.connect(signer).deposit(amountIn);
  await dai.connect(signer).approve(UniContract, amountIn);
  // Swap
  let tx = await UniContract.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn);
  await tx.wait();
  
  console.log("DAI balance", balance)
  
  await waitforme(1000);  
  
}
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          process.exit(1);
  });
```

and this is the contract that i have deployed onto the test net:

```
pragma solidity =0.7.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

contract SwapExamples {
    // NOTE: Does not work with SwapRouter02
    ISwapRouter public constant swapRouter =
        ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
    address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

    /// @notice swapInputMultiplePools swaps a fixed amount of WETH for a maximum possible amount of DAI
    /// swap USDC --> DAI --> USDC
    function swapExactInputMultihop(uint amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint amountOut)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            DAI,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(
                    DAI,
                    uint24(500),
                    USDC,
                    uint24(500),
                    DAI
                ),
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            });
            
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);
    }
}
```

There could be other issues that i am missing so if anyones finds anything else wrong with my script please let me know i would really appreciate it

So i have tried to search online to see if i could fix this, essentially i need a continous transaction to be made on the testnet from Dai -> usdc -> Dai again and the balance of dai should deplete until the loop breaks when 10% of the balance is gone.

I believe the main culprit could be either this part:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
var fs = require('fs');
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
```

where i might be missing something or

```
async function main() {

const {PRIVATE_KEY} = process.env;
const {INFURA_GORELI_ENDPOINT_KEY} = process.env;

let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(`https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/${INFURA_GORELI_ENDPOINT_KEY}`)

let signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const abi = await getABI();
const UniContract = new ethers.Contract(DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);
const balance = await dai.balanceOf(signer);

  for (let i = 0; i < 111; i++) {

  const amountIn = balance

  if (amountIn.mul(10).lte(balance.mul(9))) {break;}

  await dai.connect(signer).deposit(amountIn);
  await dai.connect(signer).approve(UniContract, amountIn);
  // Swap
  let tx = await UniContract.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn);
  await tx.wait();
  
  console.log("DAI balance", balance)
  
  await waitforme(1000);  
  
}
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: GetContractAt is async, and you don’t await it.

Answer (score 0):

this function is `async`

```
 const dai = ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);
```

You have to `await` it but you cannot await on top level. you have to call it inside an `async` function. in your case you have to call it inside `main`

```
async function main() {
   const dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);
}
```